# How to come from 5th to 2nd Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

There are five activities in my project A,B,C,D,E

The order of Activities are A -> B -> C -> D -> E

I need to press button in Activity E and It should go to Activity B

I dont want to start the activity B I want the data as it is in Activity B

My code is on button click on Activity E

```
Intent(this, B::class.java).apply {
            startActivity(this)
        }
        finish()
```

Comment: i don't know whether it is correct or not , but you can use ```startActivityForResult``` to every activity after B activity

Comment: yes finally I used startActivityForResult only.. but Is there any alternatives? like setting flags to intent object?

Comment: You can use fragment instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag.

```
val intent = Intent(this,  B::class.java).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        startActivity(this)
}
```

If you set it flag to intent, and the activity B is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of B activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed (in your case C, D, E activities) and this Intent will be delivered to the B activity as a new Intent.

See also https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 0):

```
val intent = Intent(this,B::class.java)  
startActivity(intent)
```

You can use this instead of your Code .